# Minecraftpocketedition username double § problem

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

On minecraft PE I accedently typed in two § instead of one § for my username and whenever I try joining a server it says invalid name and I can't change my username! Why?

(This is not a duplicate from the invalid name problem because I typed in §§ it didn't just come up!)

Comment: You can't change your username? Does the option not show up in settings?

Comment: @Private Pansey,Unionhawk,galacticninja,mordi3K,TZHX I don't get why it is a duplicate because I typed in §§ it dididn't just come up!

Comment: @Frankiesmagicfootball "§" isn't an allowed character. A-Z, 0-9 and afaik space and - is allowed.

Comment: @Frankiesmagicfootball I have no idea what you mean by "I typed in §§ it dididn't just come up!". If this is not a duplicate, you have to tell us exactly what you did and why the answers of the duplicate question don't help.